# External IP Address of the client

Tags: java, ip-address, external

Sounds funny, but how can I get the external IP address from a client?

I tried few things, but didn't work for me.

in first place I tried

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

and I am getting the result as: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

in second place I tried

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
ip.getHostAddress());
```

and I am getting the result as: 127.0.0.1

in third place I tried

```
        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/");
        BufferedReader inIP = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

        String IPStrOld = inIP.readLine(); //IP as a String
        String IPStrNewest = IPStrOld.replace("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: ", "");
        String IPStr = IPStrNewest.replace("</body></html>", "");
```

but I get the external IP of the server only

and for the last place

```
        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp");
        BufferedReader inIP = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
        String ip = inIP.readLine();
```

this is the same, I get the external IP of the server only

So, what's the deal?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the external IP address of a client"? Can you give some concrete examples? For instance, what if a client is accessing the server over a local area network? If that is not a valid scenario, that should be explained in the question. And by concrete examples, I mean that you should detail where the client is located (ie. which type of network), how it reaches the server, which IP addresses are in play, and which one you're trying to get hold of.

Comment: the IP address of the router, I hope you understand now?. "where the client is located" - this is what I want to know :) + client's IP ie: 103.456.768.22

Comment: @hoss Ok, then when the client is making a request to you, the address translation will happen (NAT or proxy server) and your server will accept the remote connection of the user. This connection should provide you with the client's translated address. Hence, I maintain that jzd's answer is the correct one and there is an extra issue to solve. What is the type of your 'request' object?

Comment: ok, here it is HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your client is using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (network address translation) it may not have an external address. Most often, in my experience, this is the case. At work, my web requests go through a proxy so the web server can only determine this address. At home I use NAT via a server so this laptop I'm typing on has no external address. The closest thing is what is returned from 'whatismyip', my server address, through which I may sometimes forward ports that go to my laptop.

Comment: and eventually, there is no solution? in my application I need to check from which country is the client and/or from wich IP he/she made that order

Comment: I don't think so. I'm in Australia, and the work proxy is in Singapore...does wonders for localised web sites :(

Comment: No, this answer is not correct. If a user is accessing the web via NAT, the NAT will assign it a temporary public IP address and port for all connections. Otherwise, the Internet would not work. This address is not permanent, but it does exist.

Comment: No @JVerstry, you are wrong. The packets are rewritten by the router when they are passed from the internal to external network or vice versa. There is no temporary address. Read the link I provided.

Comment: I agree, but that is not what I mean. From hoos's side, not matter if the address is translated by a NAT or a proxy server, this address is created and should be visible for him.

Comment: "The NAT will assign it a temporary public IP address" - this is just wrong. The address the web server sees is just my server address. My server does not pass any other information - the translation table is in my server, and only it knows how to route packets back to the right internal network address.

Comment: The confusion is likely due to the wording of this answer. What sje397 is saying is that the client is not getting *its own personal public IP address*, but rather is mapped to an existing IP address already used by the NATting router. As such, there *is* a public address in play here, but it is not the property of the client device, nor is one created for the client. Creation of public IP address usually involves the provider of the network connection on the outside of the NATting router.

Comment: 100% agree with you. Meaning the client DOES have an external address from a WAN perspective. This is (most often) a combination of the public IP address of the server + a free port. My understanding of the question is that hoss cannot get access to this address/port combination from his side while he should.

Comment: @JVerstry - I think I know what you're saying - but the port is likely to change for each connection, so it's pretty useless.

Comment: @sje397 True, but it is still valuable forensic information. I think the OP needs to be clarified. If hoss is trying to get his own translated address, then he needs a WAN based server with a public IP address who can read it and return it.

Answer (score 2):

Running "whatismyip" actions on code run on the server is only going to give you the server address.

Also,

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0363.html

From that link:

```
<%
out.print( request.getRemoteAddr() );
out.print( request.getRemoteHost() );
%>
```

You may not get the real client IP if a the client is behind a proxy, you will get the IP of the proxy and not the client. However, the proxy may include the requesting client IP in a special HTTP header.

```
<%
out.print( request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") );
%>
```

Comment: request.getRemoteAddr() always gets the IP as localhost (127.0.0.1) even is this is the server or the client

Comment: ?  That doesn't match what you said in your question.

Comment: maybe, but the 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 it too an invalid IP :)

Comment: @hoss jzd's answer is the correct one. Now if you don't get valid IP address from the connection created by the user's request, then your issue is coming from somewhere else. If you are using sockets, you should be able to retrieve that information, especially if your client is receiving answers from your server.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.dyndns.org:8245/");
    BufferedReader inIP = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
    String IPStrOld = inIP.readLine(); //IP as a String
    String IPStrNewest = IPStrOld.replace("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: ", "");
    String IPStr = IPStrNewest.replace("</body></html>", "");
```

works fine for me! I got my router IP address with it! (in a string like XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)

The code for the website:

http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp

does not work anymore...