# Getting IP address of client in Jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I want to fetch Ip address of client in my jsp page and want to store on my Database.

I am using following code in Jsp page to fech Ip address, but it is showing the servers Ip address.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" value="<%=request.getRemoteAddr()%>"/>
```

Comment: is your client and server are on same machine ?

Comment: Check this question: [External IP Address of the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040181/external-ip-address-of-the-client)

Comment: Why do you want to get the clients address?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In usual case the method `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` (or `getRemoteHost()` and `getRemotePort()`) should returns details of the actual client.
But, if its routed through a proxy, or  a differnt servlet engine you would be getting ip of those machines.  To tackle these situation you could try below operations

```
request.getHeader("VIA")             --> Gateway   
request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")--> IPaddress
```

But this could return null if the request is directly from the client. You may handle the situation with some additional conditions to get valid data.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get the client IP address from the server side with the `request` object is never a reliable method.

The most reliable ones tend to get executed on the client side, with ActiveX, Applets, or Javascript just to name a few. However, this also poses some challenges. Check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391979/1434089) just so you know what you're up against ([This is my prefered answer from that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391990/1434089))